# ViewDoesNotExist at /

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I receive the following error:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /
'<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">' is not a callable or a dot-notation path
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
'<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">' is not a callable or a dot-notation path
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in get_callable, line 102
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/mona/interviews/django/learning_site',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py3.4.egg',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python34.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 20 Jun 2016 13:18:23 +0000
```

When running this command:

```
$ python3 manage.py  runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 20, 2016 - 13:18:16
Django version 1.9.7, using settings 'learning_site.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 134, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 376, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 248, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 255, in callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/functools.py", line 428, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 102, in get_callable
    "'%s' is not a callable or a dot-notation path" % lookup_view
django.core.exceptions.ViewDoesNotExist: '<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">' is not a callable or a dot-notation path
[20/Jun/2016 13:18:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 71836
```

Here's what I have in `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world()),
]
```

and here's what I added to views.py in the same directory as urls.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def hello_world():
    return HttpResponse('Helloooo world!')
```

can you point me to the cause of problem and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Your hello_world view should take a single positional argument: `def hello_world(request):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `urlpatterns` you supply the functions that django should call. This means that you need to supply just the function and not call them. Simply remove the `()` at the end and it should work:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world),
]
```

You also need to change your function to take `request` as the argument:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse('Helloooo world!')
```

Django is actually quite nice and tells you here that it is trying to call a `HTTPRespone`. This usually is a tell that you should supply the callable itself instead of the called instance.

Answer (score 5):

Replace:

```
url(r'^$', views.hello_world()),
```

with:

```
url(r'^$', views.hello_world),
```

i.e., don't call the function, just pass the callable to the url configuration.

Comment: TypeError at /
hello_world() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Got this error when changed to what you said

Comment: To fix the `TypeError`, change the view so that it takes the request object: `def hello_world(request):`